# How to perfect the line joins?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, line

I'd like to perfect my linejoins. How can I accomphish this? I tried `line join=round` in the `\begin{tikzpicture}` environment, like so `\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]`, but it didn't solve the issue.

[image: top right]
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[graphics, active, tightpage]{preview}
%\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

%!tikz preamble begin
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, 3d, calc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning, backgrounds, scopes}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground} 
%!tikz preamble end

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=round,scale=1.5]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{5}
\newcommand{\boxcolor}{yellow!20!}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw[fill=\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the `line cap=round` option, but wihtout a compilabe example it may be hard to completely answer that question. `line cap` handles line endings, while `line join` handles connections between segments. As you use multiple `\draw` calls, you have issues at the line endings.

Comment: I need layers because I have stuff inside the box, which I want behind the boarders and in front of background. (Not shown in code)

Comment: You are drawing centered 2d lines in 3d space, so that so the outer edges are extending past the centers.

Comment: What does this mean? How can I improve this?

Comment: Also `line cap=round`does not result in any change/improvement.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to use  `\draw[fill=\boxcolor]` instead of `\fill[\boxcolor]` ?

Comment: None in particular. Just not knowing any better. But this has nothing to do with the issue. Clipping solved it.

Comment: You can solve the issue by saying e.g. `rounded corners=\pgflinewidth/2` (a smaller radius would also do), e.g.  in the options of the `tikzpicture` : `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=round,scale=1.5,rounded
corners=\pgflinewidth/2] ...`. (I also do not understand why one needs layers here.)

Comment: Thanks @BambOo, @JohnKormylo and @Schödinger's Cat! All answers are valid and do what I want. Initially I used something similar to @BambOo's suggestion with `scope` which for some reason was resulting in errors (LaTeX errors are mostly cryptic to me). Therefore, and because I think it also is the cleanest code, I accepted BambOos post. Sorry John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative version without `\clip` but also with `pgfonlayer`s replaced with `scope`s. Note that the `\draw[fill=\boxcolor]` were replaced with `\fill[\boxcolor]`. 
Using `\draw[fill=\boxcolor,line cap=round, line join =round]`also works fine.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1.5,line cap=round, line join =round]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{5}
\newcommand{\boxcolor}{yellow!20!}
\begin{scope}
    \node at (-0.5*\cubex,-0.5*\cubey,-0.25*\cubez) {\Huge some text};
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;

\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[on background layer={line cap=round, line join =round}]
    \fill[\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \fill[\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \fill[\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Looking back at the [`pgf-tikz` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), §45 related to the `backgrounds` library, it is explained that the options passed to `on background layer` allow to pass options to all the objects inside the `scope`, which solves the problem completely.

[image]

Comment: What's the difference of `\fill[...]` to `\draw[fill=...]` or `scope`to `pgfonlayer` so that this works?

Comment: `\draw[fill=...]` draws black lines and fills the area. `\fill[...]` only fills the area. Note that you probably meant `\path[fill=...]` which is equivalent to `\fill[...]`. The `scope` does not make much difference here but it avoids setting layers explicitely

Answer (score 3):

You can use clip to only draw the inside half of lines along the edges.  Of course, lines internal to the clip will be twice as wide.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[graphics, active, tightpage]{preview}
%\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

%!tikz preamble begin
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta, 3d, calc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning, backgrounds, scopes}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground} 
%!tikz preamble end

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,line join=round,scale=1.5]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{5}
\newcommand{\boxcolor}{yellow!20!}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
  \clip (-\cubex,0,-\cubez) -- (0,0,-\cubez) -- (0,-\cubey,-\cubez) -- (0,-\cubey,0)
    -- (-\cubex,-\cubey,0)-- (-\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \draw[red!20!] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \clip (-\cubex,0,-\cubez) -- (0,0,-\cubez) -- (0,-\cubey,-\cubez) -- (0,-\cubey,0)
    -- (-\cubex,-\cubey,0)-- (-\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=\boxcolor] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```